# Recommended settings for a Neo4j Server

Tags: java, neo4j, debian, virtual-machine

I configure a Neo4j Server (2.0.2) on a Debian Wheezy (7.5) 64bit Server in a VMware Machine. I use Oracle Java 7 Update 55 64bit. The host system is server with a Intel Xeon X5650 with 2.67GHz. The VM has 2 (virtual) cores with a limit of 1000MHz, 4GB RAM and 50GB diskspace.

What are the recommended settings for the Neo4j Server if it runs alone in this VM (like Java Stacksize, Neo4j sizes etc.)? I already increased the number of open files limit to 40000.

Answer (score 1):

Without detailed information about the structure and size of your graph, your sizing in terms of requests per timeout, query complexity and patterns, write vs. read ratio it's almost impossible to give a good advice.

You might read through http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/embedded-configuration.html for general information.

As a rule of thumb you should have the ondisc size of your graph in RAM plus the demand of the JVM including object caches.

In general virtual machines tend to have issues regarding IO latency. If you can assign native discs, preferable SSDs, do it.

Comment: The server has to process constantly reads with different complexity and every 15 - 30 minutes several batch writes jobs with a amount of 100k to 300k nodes and relations but with lower complexity. Neo4j is used as "cache" for a MySQL server - therefore a script imports/updates every 15 - 30 minutes the Neo4j server with data of the MySQL server. Neo4j is than used to present users recommendations by analysing relations. It is important that the reads will be processed as fast as possible.

Comment: I can't change anything on the VM because it was provided to us and no wishes are possible. The virtual disc space lies on a SAN.

Comment: Since you can't change the VM your tuning options are pretty much limited (4GB is tiny these days).